# adding fractions in css

Tags: css, html

i am trying to add fractions using css

```
.top{border-bottom:solid black 1px; display:inline-block; float:left}
.bottom{ display:inline-block; clear:left; float:left}
```

so they would appear in the format:

```
1
-
x
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KVDS5/78/
it works but when i try to add numbers to the equation in the sides it just moves to the left side, how can i set the css so it won't effect the equation order?

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to 1/x ?

Comment: yes, but i want the format to look like on paper, so i can write longer expressions and it will still look like a fraction

Comment: CSS is not meant for rendering Mathematical expressions, consider using http://www.mathjax.org/ instead

Comment: isn't there any simple solution for this in css?

Comment: You are using font tag which is deprecated, also, if you want to use a fraction, use `border-bottom` and that will solve the issue

Comment: You can just have the top part in one container and have border bottom for the line and the another container for the bottom part. Center the text in both containers

Comment: i am using a border-bottom, but i need them to be on on top the other

Comment: My advice is you need to wrap the added numbers. Why do you need them outside the span? Can you make a screenshot of what you try to achieve visually?

Comment: @atikot don't use it on a single character, split an element horizontally and not just a single character

Comment: thanks guys, Mark Nijboer solution was exactly what i looked for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.fraction {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.fraction, .top, .bottom {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

This is how I did it.
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/yQm72/1/

Comment: @atikot This one is with a big number on top: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/yQm72/2/

Comment: +1, just a suggestion, use div for wrapping instead of class, would semantically make sense

Comment: @atikot If this is the solution to your question then please mark it as so.