# vertically position a span for fractions

Tags: html, css

i want to display fractions, and i adapted this css:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438923/3787706

but now i want to add more to the equation, but the operation sign (like '+') sits in the bottom line.

[image]

how can i center it between the borders? what is the reference point for the # sign? what would be the best practice? i don't want to hack it together and have it break on phones, tablets or different browser resolutions

Comment: i'm pretty sure there are better examples on the internet, maybe look for another

Comment: I started to work on this: http://jsfiddle.net/sm9ya7x6/1/

Comment: I now updated my answer to scale no matter font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version, extended from the post you referred to.

*Edit after request*

I moved the operator to the html, into an attribute, `data-operator="+"` from where the CSS read what to put into the pseudo content. One can also add an extra element into the mix but gain nothing in doing that.

Updated with a 3:rd sample using an extra element instead of a pseudo element.

```css
.test1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.test2 {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.test3 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
.fraction {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.fraction, .top, .bottom, .middle {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
.bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
.middle {
    display: block;
}
.middle ~ .middle:after {
  content: attr(data-operator);
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
}
.middle ~ .middle span {  
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
  </span>
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="middle">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="middle" data-operator="+">&nbsp;</span>
  </span>
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="test2">
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
  </span>
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="middle">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="middle" data-operator="+">&nbsp;</span>
  </span>
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="test3">
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
  </span>
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="middle">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="middle">&nbsp;<span>+</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
    <span class="bottom">6</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Src: [adding fractions in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438793/adding-fractions-in-css/24438923#24438923)

Comment: but thats fixed px.. what about responsiveness?

Comment: @user3787706 The first solution already had px set. So what you mean with "responsiveness"?

Comment: yes i removed the 12px in my implementation. 2px padding is no problem, but i think this vertical alignment in px will drift off on different devices

Comment: @user3787706 I updated my answer with a more responsive version :)

Comment: this looks nice, but is there a way to not have to set the content in css? (it is dynamic)

Comment: @user3787706 Updated my answer with how to do that.

Comment: @user3787706 Did it help you or you want one more element instead of the pseudo?

Comment: didn't work much further on it until now, but it works for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Improved Version: http://jsfiddle.net/sm9ya7x6/

```css
.fraction {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.operation {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 36px;
}

.fraction,
.top,
.bottom {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

.bottom {
  padding-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
<span class="bottom">6</span>
</span>


<span class="operation">+</span>

<span class="fraction">
    <span class="top">1</span>
<span class="bottom">6</span>
</span>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar :D these Browsers. I guess you have another font-family by default once again?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to LGSon's answer, some more improvements.

```css
.fraction {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.fraction,
.top,
.bottom {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
.vertical {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="fraction">
  <span class="top">1</span>
  <span class="bottom">6</span>
</span>
<span class="fraction">
  <span class="vertical">+</span>
</span>
<span class="fraction">
  <span class="top">1</span>
  <span class="bottom">6</span>
</span>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: but thats fixed px.. what about responsiveness?

Comment: @user3787706 use another approach

Comment: @user3787706 Updated for responsiveness in `em`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar now it look very diffrent in my browser

Comment: @CodeiSir Looks like we need to use reset. These are heavily based on positions, baselines.

Comment: We can only give an answer to an extent and it should be possible for @user3787706 to take it from here to improve. `:)` That's what StackOverflow is for right?

Comment: @user3787706 I have put the `em` for more responsiveness. Did you see that? Else you can do the `translate(0, -50%)` trick.

Comment: not perfect in my browser, but it's a good starting point, i think i can tweak it to fit. thanks :)

Comment: @user3787706 You need to use `pt`, `em`, `%`. Make sure of that. Else, dealing with fonts will be a tragedy. `:(`